# How to parse a long dataframe of text using regular expressions into a dataframe [R]

Tags: regex, r, text

I have a giant data frame which I would like to turn into a more usable format. It is based on a copy-pasted text file of a schedule, where the entries have a consistent format.So, I know that each day will have the format:

```
###
Title - Date
First event
Time: 11:00 AM
Location: Address
Address line 2
Second event description
Time: 12:00 AM
Location: Address
Address
###
```

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to parse this. Basically, I want to store everything between the "###"'s as a single day, and then add events based on how many times the above format repeats, and make a string or datetime entry based on if letters are following a "Time:" or a "Location:".

However, I am really having trouble with this. I have tried putting it all into a giant dataframe where each line is a row, and then adding dummies for location rows, time rows, etc as seperate columns, but am not sure how to translate that into discrete days or events. Any help would be appreciated.

Data is public, so a sample is below -- it is a giant dataframe with one row for each row of text:

```
*Text*
###
The Public Schedule for Mayor Rahm Emanuel – January 5, 2014
There are no public events scheduled at this time.
###
The Public Schedule for Mayor Rahm Emanuel – January 6, 2014
Mayor Rahm Emanuel will greet and thank snow clearing teams from the Department of Streets and Sanitation.
Time: 11:30 AM
Location: Department of Streets and Sanitation
Salt Station
West Grand Avenue and North Rockwell Street
Chicago, IL*
*There will be no media availability.
Mayor Rahm Emanuel and City Officials will provide an update on the City’s efforts to provide services during the extreme weather.
Time: 2:00 PM
Location: Office of Emergency Management and Communications
Headquarters
1411 West Madison Street
Chicago, IL*
*There will be a media availability following.
Mayor Rahm Emanuel will greet and visit with residents taking advantage of a City warming center.
Time: 3:00 PM
Location: Department of Family and Support Services
10 South Kedzie Avenue
Chicago, IL**
*There will be no media availability.
**Members of the media must respect the privacy of residents at the facility, and can only film City of Chicago employees.
###
```

Edit:
An example output I would like is something like (sorry the code here is broken, not sure why!):

```
Date            Time      Description           Location
December 4th    9:00 AM   A housewarming party  1211 Main St.
December 5th   11:00 AM   Another big event     1234 Main St.
```

If at all possible.

EDIT 2:
Basically -- I know how to pull all this stuff out of the columns. I think my issue may really be reshaping the data intelligently. I have split it into this giant dataframe with one column where each row is a string which corresponds to a row of text int he original schedule. I then have a bunch of columns like "is_time", "is_new_entry", "is_location" which are 1 if the row is a time, new entry beginning, or location. I just don't know how to reshape this into the output above.

Comment: The `spit_vector` function in the **qdapTools** package may be of some use here: `split_vector(input, split = "Time:\\s+", include = TRUE, regex = TRUE)` but I really am not sure what exactly you're after.

Comment: Your data does not match up to the output. In general, you need to to split on the delimiters then grab the partial matching strings you want.

Comment: Basically -- I know how to pull all this stuff out of the columns. I think my issue may really be reshaping the data intelligently. I have split it into this giant dataframe with one column where each row is a string which corresponds to a row of text int he original schedule. I then have a bunch of columns like "is_time", "is_new_entry", "is_location" which are 1 if the row is a time, new entry beginning, or location. I just don't know how to reshape this into the output above.